# Can I make any of these lifetimes implicit?

Tags: rust

It's hard for me to read the `From` implementation without fainting from fatigue.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=070981e78c0f39a860d5f8d6cad4f627

```
struct HasLifetimes<'first, 'second> {
    sister: &'first i32,
    brother: &'second i32,
}
impl<'first, 'second> HasLifetimes<'first, 'second> {
    fn new() -> Self { 
        Self { sister: &101, brother: &10 }
    }
}
struct HasStruct<'first, 'second> {
    child: HasLifetimes<'first, 'second>,
    nephew: i32,
}
impl<'first, 'second> HasStruct<'first, 'second> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { child: HasLifetimes::new(), nephew: 1 }
    }
}

impl<'first, 'second> From<HasLifetimes<'first, 'second>> for HasStruct<'first, 'second> {
    fn from(source: HasLifetimes<'first, 'second>) -> Self {
        Self { child: source, nephew: 2 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = HasLifetimes::new();
    let b = HasStruct::from(a);
    println!("Hi! {} {} {}", b.nephew, b.child.sister, b.child.brother);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the implementations like that:

```
struct HasLifetimes<'first, 'second> {
    sister: &'first i32,
    brother: &'second i32,
}

impl HasLifetimes<'_, '_> {
    fn new() -> Self { 
        Self { sister: &101, brother: &10 }
    }
}


struct HasStruct<'first, 'second> {
    child: HasLifetimes<'first, 'second>,
    nephew: i32,
}

impl HasStruct<'_, '_> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { child: HasLifetimes::new(), nephew: 1 }
    }
}
```

Comment: cool! I assume the same isn't possible for trait implementations, or you would have mentioned it?

Comment: Nope, because you must specify that the lifetimes are the same in the two structs. Otherwise, there is a borrow checker issue.

Comment: @PabloTatoRamos For many use cases, you can make the lifetimes `'first` and `'second` the same, which will further simplify the code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach sure, but that wasn't the case here 